# mark.js works in html but not classic asp

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP file that generates the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blog.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mark.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function performMark(keyword) {
                var options = {
                    "element": "span",
                    "className": "highlight",
                    "acrossElements": true
                };
                markInstance.mark(keyword, options);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="iframeBody">
        <div id="blog_post_container">
            <div id="blog_post_container_header">
                <div id="blog_search_form_container">
                    <form method="post" name="frmBlogSearch" id="frmBlogSearch" action="blog.asp"><input type="hidden" name="btid" value="1" /><img src="images/icon_refresh.png" onclick="returnToBlogList('1','');" title="Clear Search Criteria" /><input type="text" name="txtSearchCriteria" value="summary" /><img src="images/search.gif" alt="Search Blog" onclick="searchBlog();" title="Search Blog" /></form>
                </div>
                <div id="blog_type">Blog</div>
            </div>
            <div id="blog_search_title">Search Results - All Blog Posts That Contain &quot;summary&quot;</div>
            <div id="blog_list" class="search_context">
                <div id="blog_post_98">
                    <div class="blog_title"><a href="?bid=98&txtSearchCriteria=summary">Second Test With Summary</a></div>
                    <div class="blog_summary"><a href="?bid=98&txtSearchCriteria=summary">Another awesome summary. It can be very long. We are not limiting it. Just keep typing. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. UPDATE - NEW THING!!</a></div>
                    <div class="blog_dates">
                        Posted: 11/8/2016 11:54:26 PM
                        <div class="blog_updated_date"><i>Updated: 11/17/2016 1:30:29 AM</i></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog_author">Posted By: Me</div>
                </div>
                <hr class="gradient" />
                <div id="blog_post_97">
                    <div class="blog_title"><a href="?bid=97&txtSearchCriteria=summary">First Test With Summary</a></div>
                    <div class="blog_summary"><a href="?bid=97&txtSearchCriteria=summary">This is the summary for a Blog post</a></div>
                    <div class="blog_dates">
                        Posted: 11/8/2016 11:29:53 PM
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog_author">Posted By: Me</div>
                </div>
                <hr class="gradient" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var markInstance = new Mark(document.querySelector(".search_context"));
            performMark("summary");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the ASP file, the performMark function is not highlighting the word "summary" anywhere. If I cut and paste the same exact markup and put it in an html file in the same folder, it works fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you check the network tab in the developer tools to make sure that mark.min.js was loaded?

Comment: Yes, the mark.min.js file is loading. Also, there are no errors in the Console tab.

Comment: For me it works too. It's hard to help you with a working HTML file.

Comment: I know right!!?!?! I am so frustrated right now. It makes no sense. I have no idea what to even try. Was hoping someone may have had a similar experience with classic-ASP and could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Despite console being blank, is there any chance that the JS file is not present or the DOM is not in place when the code runs ? Synchronisation issues can give apparently random bus like this. Just a thought.

Comment: I don't see how either of those could be the case, at least not in my mind. Both the ASP file and the HTML file are running from the same folder and they both produce the exact same markup. The Mark function runs at the end of the file so the DOM should be loaded at that point I would think? Unless there's something I am unaware of in how an ASP file runs that prevents the DOM being loaded until later?

Comment: Here are two URLs: http://www.moyl.com/testblog.asp and http://www.moyl.com/test2.html. The ONLY difference between these files is the ASP file has the <%@ Language=VBScript %> line at the top. The rest of it is a direct copy of the html found in test2.html. If you pull these two pages up, you will see that the source is identical in both of them. Yet the ASP page does not do the highlight...or at least it doesn't for me. I have tried it on 2 separate hosts and 3 different browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox)